# sharepoint 2013 footer like global navigation

Tags: 2013, navigation, footer

I am trying to create a site in SharePoint 2013 in I have come across global navigation from site settings which can be used as a header.

Now I want to use same kind of navigation as footer? Is it possible to add another navigation such as global navigation which can be used as footer ?

PS I am new to SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the Global Navigation control then yes you can put that in footer. Actually a control can be put anywhere. The only thing is that you'll be dealing with a lot of styling and quite a lot CSS fixes.

Comment: i want global navigation used as header + another navigation which can b used as footer. is it possible ? i am using sharepoint designer 2013

Comment: Yes, you can use Default Navigation control and put another navigation that you want next to it (or below) as per your requirement. And then a lot of css fixes.
And if you're talking about making "default navigation + your another navigation" as a single control, then I am afraid it is not possible but you can put both control wherever you like.

Comment: thanx , by using what i can achieve the 1st option you mentioned global navigation + another navigation as footer ?

Comment: Open your site in SharePoint Designer, then open the Master page that you will be applying and move(cut) the navigation control along with its placeholder and paste to the footer area. Then you can add your another navigation control (if you have already created one) next to the new place of default navigation.